# What does test status postponed for a patch on d.o mean?

Tags: community-official-site, version-control

I've [added a patch](http://drupal.org/node/1349882#comment-6190164) for the [rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules). The [patch detail page](http://qa.drupal.org/pifr/test/295838) says the test status is *postponed*.

What does that exactly mean? Is there anything I should do to get the patch tested?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the current Rules branch is currently failing an already commited test. While this *should* obviously not be possible, as tests should be green before they are commited, rare circumstances will cause this to happen from time to time.

Since an already existing test *does* fail, we *know* that testing with your new patch will also fail, whether your patch is correct or not. Thus all tests are postponed until the existing and breaking test is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what Letharion said, these are the [Rules 7.x-2.x tests](http://qa.drupal.org/pifr/test/27274) that fail.

[image: screenshot]

The branch tests are the tests included in the module. To see the test ran for a module branch, you can check [this page](http://qa.drupal.org/pifr/branches); the modules are ordered alphabetically, and by their version.

[image: screenshot]

As the project tests are already failing, it doesn't make sense to test the patch; they would fail even when the patch would be correct.

The purpose of the project tests is exactly to verify that changes in the code don't introduce errors. They can be run after a commit, or before a patch is committed.

Comment: I think this question should be marked under `faq`, because it is useful information which most of us didn't know before.

Comment: If we did that with everything "most didn't know", the faq would become rather long. :)

Comment: @Letharion : yes, that makes sense to me :)